Midi instruments start in tune, then go out of tune after a few minutes (UbuntuStudio)
I have no clue what's happening here. As per the title, midi instruments start in tune, then after around 7-8 minutes go slightly sharp. This has been true for Yoshimi, Calf Organ and others.
This does not happen with samples.
This does not happen with Windows VSTs running through YaBridge.
It happens on my laptop as well as my desktop. I have tried multiple keyboard controllers in case it was a hardware issue.
The issue does not happen on Windows with the same hardware.
This is with UbuntuStudio 24.04.
I'm all out of ideas. It's been 4 months since I've been able to record any synths. My students are getting tired of guitar/drums/bass backing tracks :p
Failing this being fixed, what distros are people using to record audio?
